webscoket++ for realtime visualization, get bad connections
I want to achieve realtime visualization UI client, the images data should be sent from C++ server to UI client. I am using websocket++ library to create a server class and call this class in main.cpp to achieve this goal. However, when I call send_image() function in a for loop in main.cpp. I got this error:
"An uncaught exception occurred: Bad Connection".
Atually ,at first, I put the context of send_image() function in the on_open() function, I didn't get this error. However, if I put context of send_image() function in the on_open() function. This  on_open() function will just be called once when the new connection was created, then just one image can be sent. Therefore, I made send_image() function list as a member function of my server class. Then I can call this send_image() function in a for loop in the mian.cpp to send images continuously. However, I got above error: "An uncaught exception occurred: Bad Connection".
What I have tried is shown as following:
method 1: put the context of send_image() function in the on_open member function. This is the server class:
server.h file
class ImageServer {
public:
    ImageServer(cv::Mat img);
    void setImage(const cv::Mat& img) { img_ = img; }  // Setter method for img_
    void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl);
    void run();

private:
    server m_server;
    cv::Mat img_;
};


server.cpp file
ImageServer::ImageServer(cv::Mat img) : img_(img) {
    m_server.init_asio();
    m_server.set_open_handler(std::bind(&ImageServer::on_open, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void ImageServer::on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    server::connection_ptr con = m_server.get_con_from_hdl(hdl);
    std::vector<uchar> buffer;
    cv::imencode(".png", img_, buffer);
    con->send(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), websocketpp::frame::opcode::binary);
}

void ImageServer::run() {
    m_server.listen(19002);
    m_server.start_accept();
    m_server.run();
}

then I call this class in the main.cpp
ImageServer imageServer;
    std::thread server_thread([&imageServer]
                              { imageServer.run(); });
for (int imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < dim.nB; ++imageIndex)
    {
 CHECK(cudaMemcpy(bscan_host, RR_abs + imageIndex * imageSize, imageSize * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        cv::Mat Bscan(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_32F, bscan_host);

cv::normalize(Bscan, Bscan, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
        Bscan.convertTo(Bscan, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat Img_show;

        cv::Point2f center = cv::Point2f(ScreenWidth / 2, ScreenHeight / 2); // 极坐标在图像中的原点
        cv::warpPolar(Bscan, Img_show, cv::Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight), center, 1 * center.x,
                      cv::INTER_LINEAR + cv::WARP_POLAR_LINEAR + cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
cv::imshow("Img_show", Img_show);
        cv::waitKey(1)；

        imageServer.setImage(Img_show);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }

however, in this case, just the first image was sent from server to UI client, since just when the connection was created, the on_opens() function was call once, so the for loop have no effect, and realtime visualization can't be achieve.
Then in method 2, I make the send_image() become a member function of server class, just like this
server.h
typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

class ImageServer {
public:
    ImageServer();
    // void setImage(const cv::Mat& img) { img_ = img; }  // Setter method for img_
    void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl);
    void send_image(const cv::Mat& img);
    void run();

private:
    server m_server;
   websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl_; 
   std::mutex mutex_;
};

server.cpp
ImageServer::ImageServer()  {
    m_server.init_asio();
    m_server.set_open_handler(std::bind(&ImageServer::on_open, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}
void ImageServer::on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    hdl_ = hdl;
}

void ImageServer::send_image(const cv::Mat& img) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    server::connection_ptr con = m_server.get_con_from_hdl(hdl_);

    // Check the connection state
    if (con->get_state() != websocketpp::session::state::open) {
        std::cout << "Connection is not open, cannot send image." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::vector<uchar> buffer;
    cv::imencode(".png", img, buffer);
    con->send(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), websocketpp::frame::opcode::binary);
}

void ImageServer::run() {
    m_server.listen(19002);
    m_server.start_accept();
    m_server.run();
}

Then I call this class in mian.cpp
crow::SimpleApp App;

    CROW_ROUTE(App, "/command/<string>")
    ([&](crow::request &req, crow::response &res, const std::string &command)
     {
         if (command == "start")
         {
    // server.start_sending();
    for (int imageIndex = 299; imageIndex < dim.nB; ++imageIndex)
    {
         if (command == "stop")
         {
             break; // 
         }
        CHECK(cudaMemcpy(bscan_host, RR_abs + imageIndex * imageSize, imageSize * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        cv::Mat Bscan(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_32F, bscan_host);
    
        cv::normalize(Bscan, Bscan, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
        Bscan.convertTo(Bscan, CV_8UC1);
       

        cv::Mat Img_show;

        cv::Point2f center = cv::Point2f(ScreenWidth / 2, ScreenHeight / 2); // 极坐标在图像中的原点
        cv::warpPolar(Bscan, Img_show, cv::Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight), center, 1 * center.x,
                      cv::INTER_LINEAR + cv::WARP_POLAR_LINEAR + cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
 imageServer.send_image(Img_show);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));

        cv::imshow("Img_show", Img_show);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }

    server_thread.join();
     }
  });

    App.port(18081).multithreaded().run();

here, for synchronization, I used a crow route to send command from UI client to C++ server when the websocket connection was created. And then when the command was received, the for loop will start.
However, in this case, the for loop was blocked by this line
imageServer.send_image(Img_show);
No any image was sent to UI, I don't know why when I put this send_image() code part outside the on_open() function, it can't work and generate error: "An uncaught exception occurred: Bad Connection"， actually, I have add lock in send_image() and on_open() function, but it also have no effect
 std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
Does anyone know why this error occurs? Actually, my final goal is to achieve realtime visailization, so I use a for loop to send 500 images to UI, so as to mimic this function.
Hope get effective suggestions from you guys, thank you very much.
